# Calling a non-static method when trying to Implement an Interface using Java

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm working on a simple calculator assignment where I need to use a Java Interface in the implementation of the code. I have set up the Interface as follows:

```
public interface OperationInterface {

    // create symbolic constants to define operation options
    static final int ADDITION = 1;
    static final int SUBTRACTION = 2;
    static final int MULTIPLICATION = 3;
    static final int DIVISION = 4;

    // return answer to requested calculation as a string
    public String toString(int argumentOne, int argumentTwo);
}
```

I then have my 'Add' class as follows:

```
public class Add implements OperationInterface {
    // override toString method by returning answer to calculation as a string
    public String toString(int argumentOne, int argumentTwo)
    {
        return "" + (argumentOne + argumentTwo);
    }
}
```

I am then trying to call this Add.toString() method from my client process as follows:

```
mOut.print(Add.toString(argumentOne, argumentTwo));
```

where mOut is an ActivityInterface. My current problem is that toString is underlined red in Android Studio with the error 'Non-static method toString(int, int) cannot be referenced from a static context. If I make the toString method static I get a different error in the Add class. I guess my approach is wrong so I'd appreciate some guidance.

Also, I would like to use my static final int's to determine which class to call, e.g. if (operation == ADDITION), then call Add.toString(int, int), and similar with a Subtract, Multiply and Divide class. I can't see a way to do that at present so again would really appreciate any guidance. Thanks

Comment: what´s the other error? You might want to research the meaning of the keyword `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interface defines *instance*-specific behavior, but you're trying to call `Add.toString` as though it were a *static* method. It isn't, it's an instance method.

To use an instance method, you must have an instance:

```
Add a = new Add();
mOut.print(a.toString(argumentOne, argumentTwo));
```

Regarding choosing which operation to use based on an `operation` variable, I'd probably use a `switch`:

```
switch (operation) {
    case ADDITION:
        // ...
        break;
    case SUBTRACTION:
        // ...
        break;
    //...and so on...
}
```

Remember to have a `default` clause.

There are other ways that might (or might not) be used in production code (using `Map<Integer,OperationInterface>`), but `switch` is probably the simplest, most straight-forward one for use in homework.

Being *really careful* not to actually do the homework here (as it would be a disservice to you, denying the learning opportunity), but you'd probably use the `switch` to *create* the instance, but not to do the actual call to `toString`. E.g., the code would be in very rough terms

- Declare the variable with no initial value
- Use `switch` to assign an appropriate instance to it
- After the `switch`, call `toString` on it

That means the variable needs to be of type `OperationInterface`, not `Add` (or `Subtract`, etc.). Which is probably a big part of the point of the exercise.

---

Side note: Rather than concatenating with an empty string to convert an `int` to a string, e.g.

```
return "" + (argumentOne + argumentTwo);
```

consider [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-), e.g.:

```
return String.valueOf(argumentOne + argumentTwo);
```

Comment: That's excellent and thanks for the string part too. How about using the variable 'operation' (value between 1 and 4) to directly call the associated class Add, Subtract, Multiply or Divide? It's implied that I should not use an if/else statement for this last part.

Comment: @SteveW: I've expanded the answer to cover that. I hope it gives you enough to work with, without giving you too much. I'm trying to be careful to help without actually doing the work, because however tempting it is to just show a complete example, that would be a disservice to you.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm aware of switch - just another way to do if/else imo. But your other clues have got my thoughts working so I think I can see a good way forward.

Comment: @SteveW: *"just another way to do if/else imo"* Quite. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your "toString" method is not static , so it cannot be called without creating an object for the class in which it is present.

Your code will work if the method "toString" was a static method, because static methods belong to the class and not the object, you can directly call it with the class name. That is why it says "Non-static method toString(int, int) cannot be referenced from a static context", because you are trying to access a method which is not static in a static way.

Create an object for the class and call the method you want from it.